# NSDate returns null

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I tried this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df= [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];

NSDate *dt2 = [df dateFromString:@"2011-11-23 09:44:12"];
```

But when I do:

```
NSLog(@"dt2 is %@", dt2);
```

it returns null.Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *df= [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *dt2 = [df dateFromString:@"2011-11-23 09:44:12"];

NSLog(@"dt2 is %@", dt2);
```

Here in `HH:mm:ss`, you had used `MM` for minutes instead of `mm` and `SS` for seconds in place of `ss`. That was the mistake you committed

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The basic reference for this is http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns which concludes that Parth's answer should be the right one.